# Speech to text chirp model issue in c#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to run a transcription with "chirp" model using dotnet Google.Cloud.Speech.V2 library. I need to use chirp because I need transcription with punctuation in polish and chirp is the only supported model. I created a Recognizer in my project. The thing is that when I configure a request like this:

```
BatchRecognizeRequest request = new BatchRecognizeRequest
{
    RecognizerAsRecognizerName = RecognizerName.FromProjectLocationRecognizer("graceful-wall-398407", "europe-west4", "mpa1recognizer2"),
    Files = { new BatchRecognizeFileMetadata { Uri = audioGcsUri, } },
};
```

It returns an error:

`Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="InvalidArgument", Detail="Expected resource location to be global, but found europe-west4 in resource name.")`
When I set a location to global like this:

```
BatchRecognizeRequest request = new BatchRecognizeRequest
{
    RecognizerAsRecognizerName = RecognizerName.FromProjectLocationRecognizer("graceful-wall-398407", "global", "mpa1recognizer2"),
    Files = { new BatchRecognizeFileMetadata { Uri = audioGcsUri, } },
};
```

it returns and error like this:

`Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="NotFound", Detail="Unable to find Recognizer mpa1recognizer2 from project 879395532585.")`
Recognizer seems to be configured well I can send a configuration if needed. Anyone had problem like this?

I also tried to configure recognition config like this:

```
 var recognizerRequest = new CreateRecognizerRequest
            {
                Parent = $"projects/graceful-wall-398407/locations/europe-west4",
                RecognizerId = "mpa1recognizer2",
                Recognizer = new Recognizer
                {
                    DefaultRecognitionConfig = new Google.Cloud.Speech.V2.RecognitionConfig
                    {
                        LanguageCodes = { "pl-PL" },
                        Model = "chirp"
                    }
                }
            };
```

The issue is that when I set location to europe-west4 It says it expects it to be global, when I set it to global then is says:

`Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="InvalidArgument", Detail="The model "chirp" does not exist in the location named "global".")`

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my answer from the same exact question in the [Google Cloud community forum](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Speech-to-text-chirp-model-issue/m-p/634317#M2975).

> I wasn't able to find any document/ article that explicitly says that .NET does not support chirp but there is only python on [chirp's guide](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs/chirp-model) which tells me that a version for .NET like C# is yet to be made. The guide also mentions that chirp works for [us-central1, europe-west4 and asia-southeast1](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs/chirp-model#regions), hence you have an error when using global as your location.